# Optimise problem. Find minimum amount of wire to stabilise a three leg stool

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So there is a stool, the legs are apart from each other in a triangle fashion (isosceles triangle). The length between the points is 5 , 5 and 6.

We want to stabilise this shaky stool by putting wire between the legs, in an upside down Y fashion. (see image for clear example)[image]

So This is how I tired to start:

1 said lets label the wire a,b,c.

a is the bit between the 5'st

$$height = \sqrt(34)$$ which is not useful.

$$area = 17.48$$

Can i assume that the wires are isosceles triangle since the legs form an isosceles triangle or is that a bit of a stretch?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: construct an equilateral triangle on any edge, though preferbaly the side of 6.

Hint: apply Ptolemy inequality to conclude that the sum of lengths is greater than a certain distance.